# How to retrieve the abandoned cart details in magento

Tags: php, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I am writing the REST API in Magento to retrieve the Abandoned cart details. In the API, I have tried the below code. but it is not working.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
$collection->prepareForAbandonedReport(array(1));
$collection->load();
```

Same thing I did for products count. which is working fine. Please find the code below and I need the same thing for abandoned cart detail retrieve.

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array_keys(
            $this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(), Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ)
    ));
    $this->_applyCategoryFilter($collection);
    $this->_applyCollectionModifiers($collection);
    $products = $collection->load()->toArray();
    $size = $collection->getSize();
    $productCount = new stdClass();
    $productCount->catalog_size=$size;
```

The Above code I have written in the V1.php ( inside the REST API folder).